# Isearch-forward org-timestamp in german time format

Tags: org-mode, isearch, time-date

In org mode I use a german time format for timestamps

```
(setq org-time-stamp-custom-formats '("<%a. %d.%m.%Y>" . "<%a. %d.%m.%Y %H:%M>"))
```

For example `<Fr. 25.06.2021>`. Internally this is represented as `<2021-06-25 Fr>`.

So, I can for example `isearch-forward` for `06-25` to find the time stamp, but searching for `25.06.` doesn't work.

Is there any way to configure emacs such that it works to use`isearch-forward` for a substring of the german time stamp representation?

Answer (score 0):

`org-times-stamp-custom-formats` affects the *display* of time stamps: it does not affect how the time stamp is stored in the file. `isearch` on the other hand does not care about how the display looks; it only cares about what's in the buffer.

So I believe the answer to your question is "no".

The custom time stamp format is implemented using overlays (do `C-h i g (elisp) Overlays` to read about them). You might be able to cobble up something using the functions described there, but I think it is going to be a fairly fragile thing.

Org mode really only supports the ISO time stamp format, so you are probably better off remembering that and using ISO format (sub)expressions for searching.